# Android Gridview and multiple adapters

Tags: android, layout, gridview, adapter

I'm thinking about making an activity with multiple gridviews. One grid would have one column and 10 items (cells) and I would have around 8 of these total. The gridviews are made programmatically and added to the layout. The gridviews would use cursoradapter (same one basically but different query). Basically this resembles table layout.

Below a silly illustration of what I'm trying to do. a, b and c would all be programmatically created and they'd basically use the same adapter but with different queries.

```
 a  b  c 
.__.__.__.
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
```

Is there anything that I should take into account? Is this recommended at all? If I'd use notifychange when there are new rows in database, would this update it for all the adapters?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? A table? In that case, a GridView wouldn't be a good choice.

Comment: Basically it would be a table, with each of the columns being a separate category and under one category would go several items. This resembles actually database structure in a way, except one cell would have a photo and a picture. 

This kind of structure has already been made by previous programmer, and I'm just wondering if there's any sense in this, and continuing with it (school project). I'm trying to fix the downloading process, but it's affecting the main activity, and the adapters are acting all funky.